# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Cache middleware

Tags: node.js, api, caching

I have this middleware:

```
let cacheMiddleware = (duration) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    let key = "__express__" + req.originalUrl || req.url;

    let cacheContent = memCache.get(key);
    if (cacheContent) {
      res.send(cacheContent);
      return;
    } else {
      res.sendResponse = res.send;
      res.send = (body) => {
        memCache.put(key, body, duration * 1000);
        res.sendResponse(body);
      };
      res.end();
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

I am using memory-cache npm package.
Here is API:

```
app.get("/api/teams", cacheMiddleware(3600), (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return res.json(results);
  });
});
```

I get this error:
"Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: It seems `res.end();` is not needed before `next()`

Comment: I fixed it, actually there was no need for res.end(), I deleted it and it worked(honestly I don't know that I did but it works).